# WHERE date() - dateField >= -1 data type mismatch

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working with MS Access, new to it of course, and I can't quite put my finger on why I can't get this to work. It seems like it should be obvious to me, since this has to be a common query. I've tried searching here and the rest of the web but what I find doesn't seem to work for me or just isn't similar enough.

When I try to run the following query I get "Data type mismatch in criteria expression". I want the query to return the records less than or equal to 1 day before the current date.

I am taking two date fields, combining them together, and then using `DateDiff()` to get the difference: this works as intended if I remove the WHERE statement.

```
SELECT DateDiff("d",Date(),DateValue([sDate])+TimeValue([stime])) AS Expr1, tblEncounters.EID
FROM tblEncounters
WHERE (((DateDiff("d",Date(),DateValue([sDate])+TimeValue([stime])))>=-1));
```

Then I tried a subquery:

```
'--- qryEncountersDesc ---

SELECT DateDiff("d",Date(),DateValue([sDate])+TimeValue([stime])) AS Expr1, tblEncounters.EID
FROM tblEncounters;

SELECT tblEncounters.firstName, tblEncounters.lastName, qryEncountersDesc.Expr1
FROM tblEncounters INNER JOIN qryEncountersDesc ON tblEncounters.EID = qryEncountersDesc.EID
WHERE (((qryEncountersDesc.Expr1)>=-1));
```

I've tried different ways of performing the calculation to get the date difference and they all have worked. But I can't think of what else to try for the WHERE statement. I've tried formatnumber() CDbl() etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your system is split FE/BE, is your back end Access? Or something else? Access doesn't have a 'Date' type field. It has 'Date/Time'. SQL Server has 'Date', but may not be recognized by Access as Date/Time.
If it actually is a Date/Time field, the following should work, and is also much more efficient than a calculation on a field in the where clause:

```
WHERE sDate <= Date()-1
```

Comment: I knew I was over thinking this problem. I thought it was necessary to combine the date/time field the date was entered with the date/time field the time was entered to get an accurate return of <= current date minus 1 but just using the sDate field with the WHERE statement AVG responded with proved to simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have Null values, so try to rule these out:

```
SELECT 
    DateDiff("d",Date(),DateValue([sDate])+TimeValue([stime])) AS Expr1, 
    tblEncounters.EID
FROM 
    tblEncounters
WHERE 
    (((DateDiff("d",Date(),DateValue([sDate])+TimeValue([stime])))>=-1)
    AND
    ([sDate] Is Not Null And [sTime] Is Not Null);
```

or if you have invalid entries (including Null):

```
SELECT 
    DateDiff("d",Date(),DateValue([sDate])+TimeValue([stime])) AS Expr1, 
    tblEncounters.EID
FROM 
    tblEncounters
WHERE 
    (((DateDiff("d",Date(),DateValue([sDate])+TimeValue([stime])))>=-1)
    AND
    (IsDate([sDate]) And IsDate([sTime]));
```